# Interpretation of covariates HMM depmixS4

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I would like advice on correctly interpreting the covariates for a hidden markov model I have run, using Depmixs4. I'm really struggling to find any examples at all that actually interpret covariates.

For example, in my responses I have an output of:

```
Model of type gaussian (identity), formula: sqrt(asc_dist) ~ CCL + Temperature
Coefficients: 
(Intercept)         CCL Temperature 
4.414370026 0.002329876 0.020008043 
sd  0.5600571
```

Would I be correct in interpreting this as for every unit increase in the intercept CCL increases by 0.0023, and temperature as 0.02? Or is this incorrect?

Thanks so much!

I can't find anything aimed at not statisticians! Please could someone explain at a level for not-statisticians?